# Is there a way to put a button to open the Flyout in Maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, flyout

I am making a mobile and pc application and i want to add a button to open the flyout because i don't like the button on windows in the top corner, same with android where you have to swipe. so i want to know if there is a way to add a button and disable the current way to open it.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open the FLyout with Button .

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = true;
}
```

To hide the Bar , on top of your xaml on the page

```
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
```

Comment: thanks, for the button it works but that's not what I meant for the other thing